# iPhone - Linking touch events to different classes/controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uislider

I have a UISlider inside a custom UITableViewCell named SliderCell.

I have a method in SliderCell which updates a UILabel to match the slider's value.

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender;
```

I have the same method in a viewController that uses SliderCell in it's table. Base on the value of the slider, I want to reload an NSDictionary.

When I link the UISlider to SliderCell's method, it works.
When I link the UISlider to viewController's method, it crashes the app without even displaying an NSLOG at the beginning of the method.

I linked the UISlider to the viewController by simply dragging my viewController class into my SlideCell nib. Does the app try to init another viewController instance?

How do I link it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to forget the interface builder and just do everything programmatically!!

```
SEL action = @selector(someAction:);
[myUISlider addTarget:self action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change your declaration to:

```
-(IBAction) yourSliderValueChanged: (UISlider *) sender
```

then hook up the action to the slider.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting the UISlider to the IBAction method in the viewController?  Thats all you really should need to do

Comment: When I said "link" i meant connect. After connecting to both, i touch the slider with my mouse and the app crashes.

Comment: Post the output from the console. If by linking you mean Connecting IBOutlets, an unconnected outlet shouldn't cause a crash, so something  else is going on. Post the code and the console output.

Comment: I'm not talking about IBOutlets. I am connecting UISlider to 2 IBActions in two different classes. It crashes without any output in the console.

I did find a workaround, instead putting the SliderCell in it's own nib, I placed it in my ViewController's nib and it stopped crashing.